# ruby object model and class declaration

Tags: ruby

i was trying some code about how classes are declared internally and what happens when a class is declared. I got that when a class is declared, an object of 'Class' is created and a constant with the name of the declared class is created. eg

```
MyClass = Class.new
MyClass.class => Class
MyClass.superclass => Object
Class.constants.include? :MyClass => true
```

i also tried

```
x = Class.new => #<Class:0xd886938> 
x.class => Class 
x.superclass => Object 
Class.constants.include? :x => false #why so???
```

it means that 'x' is a class. i m confused cause

```
class x
  def say_hi 
    'hi'
  end
end
```

gives

```
SyntaxError: (irb):121: class/module name must be CONSTANT
```

why is this happening?

---UPDATE---

i tried

```
def x.x_method
  'x class method'
end
```

and did

```
x.methods.include? :x_method => true
```

similarly

```
x.singleton_methods.include? :x_method => true
```

and mainly

```
x.methods - MyClass.methods => [:x_method]
```

The above line points that `x` is a class since it's an object of class `Class`. Since all user defined classes are objects of class `Class`, then their initial methods should also be the same unless some singleton method is declared for a specific class(`x` in the above case has a singleton method)

```
x => #<Class:0xd886938>
obj_x = x.new  => #<#<Class:0xd886938>:0xd30caac> 
obj_x.class => #<Class:0xd886938>
```

The above code further strengthens the assumption that `x` is a class since it's allowing me to create new objects. if `x` would have been an instance then `new` would have failed with an error.

My question is that, why is ruby allowing me to declare a class in a particular fashion? and if it isn't a class then why is it behaving like one?

Comment: @mbratch but then everything is ruby is an object. ie an instance of class Class. say, class String is an instance of class Class.

Comment: x is a reference to a class. You can't access the class from its name because it doesn't have one, since ruby expects all class names to be constants and you haven't provided one. Hence the `SyntaxError: (irb):121: class/module name must be CONSTANT` error. The only way you can access this class you created is from this reference you stored in x.

Comment: Try the following commands and see how they differ from what you got with `x`. Instead of seeing references to an arbitrary unnamed class in the form of #<Class:0xd886938>, which is what `x` references, you'll see the class name.                               `obj_MyClass = MyClass.new` and `obj_MyClass.class`

Answer (score 4):

The Ruby interpreter only sees things that start with an uppercase letter as constants. That's why your "class" `x` isn't included in `Class.constants`

From [This](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/):

> Naming conventions
>
> Ruby enforces some naming conventions. If an identifier starts with a
>   capital letter, it is a constant. If it starts with a dollar sign ($),
>   it is a global variable. If it starts with @, it is an instance
>   variable. If it starts with @@, it is a class variable.

Since class names are supposed to be constants, `x` in your code isn't the name of the class. It is a variable that holds a class, that happens to have no proper assigned name. (Which you can verify by entering `x.name` and seeing it returns `nil`, as suggested by [@ZachKemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650630/zach-kemp) on his answer)

**In short, you can't give a class a name that starts with a lowercase character in Ruby.**

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, you can treat classes as first class objects in Ruby. In the case where you create a new class as `x = Class.new`, you've assigned a class instance object to a variable, which is not the same as giving it a name (you can send the query method `x.name` to verify the name is `nil`). You can then assign that variable to a constant (`MyClass = x`) to give it a permanent name.

The `class` declaration is a keyword that expects a constant to begin with. Both methods of creating classes create the same thing (an instance of `Class`), and you can use either method you wish (though the first is generally only used in special circumstances).

Comment: `x.name` goes from `nil` to `MyClass`. Which makes sense, but it's weird to think that assignment should affected the assigned's semantics

Comment: It doesn't change the behavior of `x`. It changes the behavior of the object that `x` points to, which happens to be the same object that `MyClass` points to. Actually, it doesn't even change *that* behavior: the contract of `Class#name` says that it returns the first constant the object has been assigned to and `nil` otherwise. `x` doesn't have behavior. `x` is a variable, variables aren't objects, only objects have behavior.